# How to modify Email Confirmation message - Firebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I am using email & password authentication provided by [Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.User#sendEmailVerification).

Below is the message the user gets, when they confirm their email address. Is there any way to customize the below message.

I would like to add a link to this message so that the users can be directed to the website. Can someone please suggest, how I could achieve this.

[image]

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can customize this page by setting up a [custom email action handler](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/custom-email-handler).

From there:

> To customize your Firebase project's email action handler, you must create and host a web page that uses the Firebase JavaScript SDK to verify the request's validity and complete the request. Then, you must customize your Firebase project's email templates to link to your custom action handler.

But you should really just follow the link and read the entire page on the Firebase site as it contains a great description and sample code.

Answer (score 0):

This page explains it very well.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/custom-email-handler

The only thing I dont like is that the email message body cannot be customized. Allowing a Mandrill integration would be awesome imo.