# Customize Firebase email template

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

When a user creates an account using firebase, I use the `firebaseUser.sendVerficiationEmail()` to send a verification link to the user. It works perfectly. However, the problem is that the email looks unprofessional and ugly. I know apps that use Firebase, such as "pic-collage", and their verification email looks pretty with their app logo on the top, and the verification link is a button.

Firebase template doesn't allow me to customize anything other than 'sender name' and 'action url'. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please refer to this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39470459/how-to-modify-email-confirmation-message-firebase

Answer (score 5):

I checked and it does not seem that this is available as a ready made feature.  So i am guessing the other companies you mentioned having customized verification emails have had to code them.

For that you could create a Firebase cloud functions listening for auth.onUser().user().onCreate(user), from that function you would send a custom email to the user with a link to another Firebase cloud function that one would be an https.onRequest which would complete the email verification process on it's invocation.